# getting an error after executing registration form in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am trying to execute the registercase.jsp page which is having some form detail after submitting these detail towards insert.jsp getting an below error in tomcat logs.please help me if possible.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
 to use near ') values('null','null','null',null)' at line 1com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that c
orresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') values('null','null','null',null)' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
        at org.apache.jsp.insert_jsp._jspService(insert_jsp.java:75)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**Query -**

```
int i=st.executeUpdate ("insert into  issue_creating(issue_id,case_title,Problem_Submit,Problem_De‌​scr,) values('"+Issue_ID+"','"+Case_Title+"','"+Problem_Submit+"',‌​'"+Problem_Descr+"')‌​");
```

Comment: Need your MySQL query here, there's an unmatched `'` somewhere.

Comment: @Mohit Bhardwaj please show your query

Comment: please post the query you have executed. there is nothing wrong with posting it since you need help.

Comment: total 4 attribute(issue_id,case_title,Problem_Submit,Problem_Descr) are their in this query which need to be filled during regsitration of case.  int i=st.executeUpdate ("insert into issue_creating(issue_id,case_title,Problem_Submit,Problem_Descr,) values('"+Issue_ID+"','"+Case_Title+"','"+Problem_Submit+"','"+Problem_Descr+"')");

Answer (score 0):

You should organize query in well formed insert sentence.

1. there should not be any extra comma(,) here - **Problem_De‌​scr,**

It should be -

```
int i=st.executeUpdate (
"insert into issue_creating(issue_id,case_title,Problem_Submit,Problem_De‌​
scr) values('"+Issue_ID+"','"+Case_Title+"','"+Problem_Submit+"',‌​
'"+Problem_Descr+"')‌​");
```

Kindly use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in future to avoid such issues.

I hope this will help.